# Creating custom Linux image with Yocto using TI sitara am335x devkit compiler

Tags: linux, toolchain, texas-instruments, yocto

I want to use Yocto to build a linux dist from my own sources (not Arago sources).

I have installed Yocto eclipse plugin, but I can't configure the compiler toolchain.

I have the ti-sdk-am335x-evm-07.00.00.00 SDK installed, and would like to use it
to compile my own dist.

In the Yocto Project ADT preferences in eclipse, what do I specify for:
Toolchain Root Location
And
Sysroot Location?

It won't show up a target architecture, when I try to configure it. What folders should I set?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you built the toolchain, or otherwise made it available. Try this:

> bitbake meta-ide-support

That will build a script that you can source in another directory to have access to the toolchain.

Did you check out the [Yocto Manua](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#configuring-the-eclipse-yocto-plug-in)l? Specifically, look at section:
4.2.2.1.4.1. Configuring the Cross-Compiler Options

What I've gotten to work is this:

Toolchain Root Location: the manual says the top of the build directory, but for me it won't work unless I have it at build/tmp. In other words, the Toolchain Root Directory is the directory right above where the environment setup script got built.

Sysroot Directory: build/tmp/sysroots/

Also, try with "Standalone pre-built toolchain" selected instead of "Build system derived toolchain," [as discussed here](https://communities.intel.com/message/222918).